# OneToMany entity parent field giving null after being set by parent

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm trying to submit a form with `Quiz` as form backing entity and some `Question` inside of it.

These two entities are related in a bidirectional association:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = { "questions" })
@Entity
@Table(name = "quiz")
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_quiz")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idQuiz;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quiz", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> questions = new LinkedList<>();

    public Quiz() {
                // Creating a Quiz with at least one question
        addQuestion(new Question());
    }

    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        this.questions.add(question);
        // Setting Question parent for bidirectional association
        question.setQuiz(this);
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = { "quiz" })
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_question")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idQuestion;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", referencedColumnName = "id_quiz")
    private Quiz quiz;
}
```

What I'm doing in my controller when loading the form is the following:

```java
@GetMapping("/quiz")
    public String quizPage(Model model) {
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz();
                // At this point quiz.questions contains one question object with its quiz field set.
        model.addAttribute("quiz", quiz);

        return "teacher/quiz";
    }
```

And then I post it to the following endpoint:

```java
    @PostMapping("/process-quiz")
    public String processQuiz(@Valid @ModelAttribute Quiz quiz) {

        /*
// At this point, quiz.questions contains the question filled in the form but with its quiz field null
// I need to do this to set it again manually
                   for(Question question : quiz.getQuestions()) {
            question.setQuiz(quiz);
        }

*/
        quizService.save(quiz);

        return "redirect:/teacher";
    }
```

The problem is that when I load the form, my `Quiz` has the `Question` added correctly with its `quiz` field association set correctly.

But when I post the form this very same `Question` has its `quiz` field null

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: It's happening because the Quiz you get from the browser in processQuiz is created and populated using reflection, based on the request parameters sent by the browser, and has absolutely nothing to do with the quiz object created in quizPage. I would really not use entities as command objects. They're not the same thing. One models the bidirectional graph of objects in your database. The other represents the parameters sent by the browser.

Comment: Ok I see...But, if I'm adding the quiz to the model with everything fine, why can't retrieve that binded quiz in processQuiz with @ModelAttribute annotation? I thought that was possible with Spring MVC...anyway, what would you suggest to do?

Comment: I would suggest using a specific class, different than Quiz, to really model what the UI is submitting to the server. And convert that object to a Quiz in the controller.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thank you!